# java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission

Tags: android-bluetooth

Has anyone meet the same problem as the following error message shows when calling `bluetoothDeive.createBond()` method with android 4.4 api?

> java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission

Note: `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission is already included in `AndroidManifest` file.

Comment: Check is this permission will only work for system apps

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499388/android-bluetooth-admin-permission-error

Comment: No, the questions aren't related. You can't even request the `BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED` permission as it is a privileged permission.

Answer (score 39):

Got the exact error message.

Took me an hour to realize that the bluetooth on the phone is not enabled. After turning it on, it works as expected.

Comment: I mean come on! Thank you!

Comment: So glad I read this - definitely saved me an hour! What a strange error to throw when Bluetooth is off, it has nothing to do with permissions... I guess the system tries to turn Bluetooth on but can't? Weird.

Comment: I refused to believe that that stack trace was due to my Bluetooth being off until I read your answer... I was like ... "surely cant be as stupid as that..."

Comment: I can't believe this was the problem!!!
I turned my bluetooth off and spent about an hour scratching my head on runtime permissions haha

Comment: good answer .....

Answer (score 21):

You can't use this permission if your app is a third party app (non-system app). To learn more, see Android API: [BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED)

Answer (score 1):

I run on this error, and only I can say, you need to install your app as a system privileged app, to go to system folder and try to copy app to the app folder or priv_app folder. On my Android platform, when I made folder inside priv_app folder for my app and copied my apk to it and restarted Android, everything worked OK.
I my case I added in manifest all this permissions at the beginning, but it worked only after this step above.

Answer (score -4):

try this in your manifest

```
    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

notice the user not uses-permission on the first line. Until I switched that, For some reason I kept getting

> java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission

Answer (score -4):

Try this:
1) remove "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" from your permissions.
2) remove "android.permission.BLUETOOTH".
3) add "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" and just that.
The reference says that is the only permission needed.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond()

EDIT: if you already included "bluetooth_admin", maybe its a platform problem.They may have not supported that functionality earlier.  Maybe you should target a higher min-sdk-platform , Im using Android 20 as the minimum (but never tried that function).

Comment: What is the purpose of removing **"android.permission.BLUETOOTH"**?