# I need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission to autopair device

Tags: android, bluetooth, permissions

From Build 19 you can autopair a Bluetooth Device and it works fine:

```
 Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
 m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
```

The pairing works fine, but always the mobile plays a warning sound, so I checked the Log and found the Error message.

```
E/Seitz FSPRINTER: Error occurs when trying to auto pair
W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission:
```

And now I am trying to get this `permission`.
I putted it in the `Manifest`.
Than I tried to get the `permission` with:

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED}, MY_BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_CODE);
```

But I get always `-1` in `onRequestPermissionsResult`, that means that I don't got the permission.

How can I get the permission `BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974264/java-lang-securityexception-need-bluetooth-privileged-permission)

Comment: You can't possibly able use this permission if your app is a third party app (non-system app).

Comment: From Build 19 on this permission should be able to grant, so it's not dublicate.