# Android 13 - Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-13

There are some crashes observed in production app only for Android 13 devices.

All the bluetooth related permission are declared in manifest and nearby device runtime permissions are also in place.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="33" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
        android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
  
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
        android:maxSdkVersion="31" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        android:maxSdkVersion="31" />
</manifest>
```

Crash Logs:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission: Neither user 10370 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED.
       at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:2240)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:2268)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:948)
       at com.android.bluetooth.Utils.enforceBluetoothPrivilegedPermission(Utils.java:411)
       at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.permissionCheck(GattService.java:474)
       at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.registerForNotification(GattService.java:3801)
       at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$BluetoothGattBinder.registerForNotification(GattService.java:1085)
       at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$BluetoothGattBinder.registerForNotification(GattService.java:1073)
       at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGatt.java:812)
       at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1285)
       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1244)
```

Comment: Are you trying to turn on  bluetooth hardware directly? Have you seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19974264/12749998)? Looks relatable.

Comment: there is a bluetooth on check.. if bluetooth is off then not going for scan/connect

Comment: Bluetooth on checking should not be a concern. You might be touching some BLE API in your code, where 3rd party apps have no privilege on it. Those API's can be touched only by system and system wide apps. Do you mind putting all relevant code where you call BLE APIs?

Comment: have you solved this problem? I have exactly the same problem as you，and haven't find any solution.

Comment: @Leeqi7 not found any solution till now

Comment: @PratikPopat If you find any solution, could you please tell me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Suggestion here that Toggling Blue Tooth resolves the issue. Issue is also happening on Android 14. https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library/issues/507

Answer (score 2):

Registering for notifications are in some cases restricted only to apps that have the `BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED` permission, which generally only is available to system apps.

It is possible that you are trying to register notifications for example on a HID service, which are banned for general app access. Or at least the Android system believes (by looking in its GATT cache) that the characteristic is a sensitive one.

Comment: I'm not registering notification for HID service. we have custom BLE device specific services and for those I am registering for notification

Comment: By following the stack trace, it appears this code decides what are the restricted characteristics/services: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/Bluetooth/+/9e0e2fb3e323616d151c7a9504501183aad15f7a/android/app/src/com/android/bluetooth/gatt/GattService.java#2442. Here we can see that HID, FIDO, Android Remote TV, LE audio services are restricted. Hence it appears your system believes the calling app is interacting with those services. I can see no other explanation, since line 4021 in the same file seems to be called according to your stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

ive been told that there has been issues with android 12 (API level 31), the android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED permission is priviledged and isnt available for 3rd party apps

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth permission of Android 12 (API 31) has been changed.

Android 12 introduces **BLUETOOTH_SCAN** , **BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE** and **BLUETOOTH_CONNECT** permissions,
Allows the app to scan for nearby devices (NearBy) without requesting location permission (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).

1. If your application looks for Bluetooth devices, such as BLE peripherals, please declare the **BLUETOOTH_SCAN** permission.
2. If your application makes the current device discoverable by other bluetooth devices, declare the **BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE** permission.
3. If your application communicates with a paired Bluetooth device, please declare the **BLUETOOTH_CONNECT** permission.
4. For legacy Bluetooth-related permission declarations, set android:maxSdkVersion to 30. This app compatibility step helps the system grant your app only the Bluetooth required when installed on a device running Android 12 or higher authority.

Since these three Bluetooth permissions are runtime permissions, user consent must be explicitly requested in the app before it can discover Bluetooth devices.
Therefore, there is a problem of Bluetooth connection permission checking. We start from this perspective (**BLUETOOTH_CONNECT**) and analyze the permission checking mechanism.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.print.BLUETOOTH " />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android .permission. BLUETOOTH_DEBUG"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might come from the OS, and there is an open issue at the moment of writing: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/317215071

From what I've read, this might come from having a BLE device with restricted services or characteristics connected before, and later on, when you try to access the service or characteristic of another device, the BLE cache makes them considered as restricted.
A possible workaround is to turn the Bluetooth off and on to refresh the cache.

I'm considering to try/catch this exception on my application to request the user to turn its Bluetooth off and on.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Nordic Github Page](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library/issues/507) toggling BlueTooth may resolve the issue.

Since this will clear the cache which seems to be part of the problem. If there was a special UUID in the cache then the error occurs.

Toggling the Bluetooth should enable the connection to succeed.

Clearing the cache with refreshDeviceCache -is a possible solution

The GitHub page has a few other ideas in theory it is fixed for them in [Issue Fix Github 558](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library/pull/518)